# Keepers with VRF Error "Callback gas limit set too low error"

Tags: solidity, contract-development, nft, chainlink, vrf

Im trying to create a dynamic nft by following the tutorial by [alchemy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNdXSMKLDi4&t=772s), the NFT should update when `performUpkeep` is called which should get a random number using VRF v2 and change the NFT token URI. 
However, when `performUpkeep` is called the VRF fails to generate a random number and gives the reason `Callback gas limit set too low`

To reproduce the problem you can use remix with this code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/KeeperCompatible.sol";

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";

contract BullBear is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, Ownable, KeeperCompatibleInterface {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    Counters.Counter private _tokenIdCounter;
    uint public /*immutable*/ interval;
    uint public lastTimeStamp;

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceFeed;
    int256 public currentPrice;

    string[] bullUrisIpfs = [
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRXyfi3oNZCubDxiVFre3kLZ8XeGt6pQsnAQRZ7akhSNs?filename=gamer_bull.json",
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRJVFeMrtYS2CUVUM2cHJpBV5aX2xurpnsfZxLTTQbiD3?filename=party_bull.json",
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmdcURmN1kEEtKgnbkVJJ8hrmsSWHpZvLkRgsKKoiWvW9g?filename=simple_bull.json"
    ];

    string[] bearUrisIpfs = [
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmdx9Hx7FCDZGExyjLR6vYcnutUR8KhBZBnZfAPHiUommN?filename=beanie_bear.json",
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmTVLyTSuiKGUEmb88BgXG3qNC8YgpHZiFbjHrXKH3QHEu?filename=coolio_bear.json",
        "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmbKhBXVWmwrYsTPFYfroR2N7NAekAMxHUVg2CWks7i9qj?filename=simple_bear.json"

    ];

    enum MarketTrend{BULL, BEAR} // Create Enum
    MarketTrend public currentMarketTrend = MarketTrend.BULL; 

    uint64 s_subscriptionId;
    address vrfCoordinator = 0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab;
    bytes32 keyHash = 0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 100000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 numWords =  2;

    uint256[] public s_randomWords;
    uint256 public s_requestId;
    address s_owner;


    event TokensUpdated(string marketTrend);

    constructor(uint256 updateInterval, address _priceFeed, uint64 subscriptionId) 
        ERC721("Bull&Bear", "BBTK")
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator)
        {
        interval = updateInterval;
        lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;

        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
        currentPrice = getLatestPrice();  
        
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        
    }

    function requestRandomness() internal {
        s_requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            3,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
            );
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256, /* requestId */ uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        s_randomWords = randomWords;

        string[] memory urisForTrend = currentMarketTrend == MarketTrend.BULL ? bullUrisIpfs : bearUrisIpfs;
        uint256 index = randomWords[0] % urisForTrend.length;

        for (uint i = 0; i < _tokenIdCounter.current(); i++) {
            _setTokenURI(i, urisForTrend[index]);
        }
        
        string memory trend = currentMarketTrend == MarketTrend.BULL ? "bullish" : "bearish";
    
        emit TokensUpdated(trend);
    }


    function safeMint(address to) public onlyOwner {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter.current();
        _tokenIdCounter.increment();
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);

        string memory defaultUri = bullUrisIpfs[0];
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, defaultUri);
    }

    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /*checkData*/) external view override returns(bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /*performData*/) {
        upkeepNeeded = (block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*perfromData*/) external override {
        if ((block.timestamp - lastTimeStamp) > interval) {
            lastTimeStamp = block.timestamp;
            int latestPrice = getLatestPrice();

            if(latestPrice == currentPrice) {
                return;
            }
            if(latestPrice < currentPrice) {
                // bear
                currentMarketTrend = MarketTrend.BEAR;
            } else {
                // bull
                currentMarketTrend = MarketTrend.BULL;
            }
            
            // Call function for randomness
            requestRandomness();

            currentPrice = latestPrice;
        }
    }

    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (,int price,,,)=priceFeed.latestRoundData();

        return price;
    }

    function setInterval(uint256 newInterval) public onlyOwner {
        interval = newInterval;
    }

    function setPriceFeed(address newFeed) public onlyOwner {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(newFeed);
    }

    function compareStrings(string memory a, string memory b) internal pure returns (bool) {
        return (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(b)));
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId)
        internal
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
    {
        super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721Enumerable)
        returns (bool)
    {
        return super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }
}
```

1. Deploy on Injected Provider - Metamask Rinkeby
   [fuacet](https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby)
2. Deploy with inputs 1,
   "0xECe365B379E1dD183B20fc5f022230C044d51404", and subscription id
   for chainlink VRF subscription.
3. Once deployed i added
   my contract as consumer to chainlink VRF subscription and registered with Keepers and fund
   with link.
4. safeMint to my address
5. performUpKeep (input value of [])

Now if you check `s_randomWords` with input 1, a random number should return but instead i get the error `Error: Returned error: execution reverted`

And a snippet of [etherscan] of the VRF call:

[image: VRF Failed]
[image: Etherscan transaction]
[image: Etherscan logs]

Comment: can you post the transaction from etherscan? the tx error details should help.

Also make sure you have funded your contract (it is the Upkeep - see https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-keepers/introduction/) and your VRF subscription(https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/introduction/#subscription-billing)

Also make sure your gaslimit is sufficiently high. The tx details should tell you if there is an out of gas error.

Answer (score -1):

You should increase the `uint32 callbackGasLimit` storage variable, which is currently set to 100000, to a higher value.

Comment: Thanks i gave this a go and no success, same issue

Answer (score -1):

I am having the same issue. I have the callbackGasLimit set to the number shown in the vrf v2 docs. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/87441)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).